# How to understand submission deadlines and reporting regulations of the European Securitisation Regulation?

Tags: european-union, securities

I am currently reading through the [Reporting Instructions](https://www.esma.europa.eu/sites/default/files/library/esma65-8-6469_securitisation_disclosure_templates_reporting_instructions.pdf) for securitisations which states for non-ABCP securitisations on page 7:

> Information on the underlying exposures for non-ABCP securitisation must be reported on a quarterly basis at the latest one month after the due date for the payment of interest.

Which is, so far, understandable.

However, there is also a [Question and Answers On the Securitisaion Regulation](https://www.esma.europa.eu/sites/default/files/library/esma33-128-563_questions_and_answers_on_securitisation.pdf) document which shows the following table on page 8:

[image]

To me it's not clea how to understand this. In particular, I cannot quite understand what the *cut-off date* is.

I understand that, e.g. having a interest payment date (IPD) of 5th of January, a report has to be submitted until the 5th of February. However, the table states that the "*data cut-off date*" is *"no more than two-months before the actual submission date*".

So which timeframe does the report have to contain then?

Is there a more concrete example for this?